# Python: lambda: find the first common element of 2 sorted infinite iterators

Tags: python, lambda, iterator, python-2.x

I am trying to get a 1 liner lambda that would return the first common element of 2 sorted iterators.

Here, I use NON FINITE iterators (like count() that will iterate forever) that you cannot convert back to a list or a set. (set(count(5)) will just crash your python).

For instance:

```
from itertools import count
x = count(7)
y = count(5)
```

The result would be 7.

Comment: How is 7 a "common element"?

Comment: It's present in both.

Comment: Why are you trying to contort this into a `lambda`? Can you use some additional variables?

Comment: well, it is a one liner challenge

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
next(x for x in count(7) for y in count(5) if x==y)
```

Comment: Does not stop, infinite loop

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11597284)

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Isn't this a self answer?

Answer (score 1):

You could use intersection as follows:

```
elt = min(set(x).intersection(set(y)))
```

Comment: this is a not a common solution. if x is xrange(10,5,-1), you cannot use a `min`. @eugene gave a better solution

Comment: @ptou compares 2 'sorted iterators'

Comment: as mentioned to @eugene, you cannot apply set neither, as the idea is to fit a non finite iterator

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
first = lambda x, y: next((a for a in x if a in set(y)), None)
```

Demo:

```
>>> x = xrange(5, 10)
>>> y = xrange(7, 11)
>>> first = lambda x, y: next((a for a in x if a in set(y)), None)
>>> first(x, y)
7
```

Comment: this is only a good solution for finite iterators, not infinite. I have edited the question to reflect this point. set(count(5)) will crash your python.

Answer (score 0):

Go over the lists until find a common object. Otherwise found will be None. Uses the fact that the iterators are sorted and don't need additional memory.

```
idx_x = 0
idx_y = 0
found = None
while idx_x < len(x) and idx_y < len(y):
    if x[idx_x] == y[idx_y]:
        found= x[idx_x]
        break
    if x[idx_x] < y[idx_y]:
        idx_x +=1
    else:
        idx_y += 1
```

Comment: the goal is to get a one liner.